# Connection Error While Synchronizing Permission for Keycloak Realm in Django

Tags: python, django, keycloak

When I try to synchronize permission for a realm from Keycloak in Django, I got the following error. Ayone knows the way of it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The up address to the keycloak server is not correct, up 0.0.0.0 is the wrong address, please check your keycloak instance ip address.